# Can't send in a second parameter to the mutation in Vue store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a nice mutation JS file like this.

```
export default {
  UPDATE_DATA: (state, data, meta) => {
    state.dataTable = data;

    if (meta === undefined)
      return;

    state.activeDataRow = meta;
  }, ...
}
```

It's being called by to different actions in the following ways.

```
context.commit("UPDATE_DATA", Map.table(payload.type, data));
context.commit("UPDATE_DATA", Map.table(payload.type, data), meta);
```

I've checked the meta being sent in the action and it's definitely not *undefined*. However, when I check the meta in the mutation, it is! Why? How do I kill this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What vuex [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) suggests is to send a payload in the second argument.

> In most cases, the payload should be an object so that it can contain multiple fields, and the recorded mutation will also be more descriptive:

So you can call it like this with payload:

```
context.commit("UPDATE_DATA", {data: Map.table(payload.type, data), meta: meta});
```

and your mutation will look like following:

```
export default {
  UPDATE_DATA: (state, payload) => {
    state.dataTable = payload.data;

    if (payload.meta === undefined)
      return;

    state.activeDataRow = payload.meta;
  }, ...
}
```

---

There is an alternet way to calling mutations as well which is called Object-Style Commit. You can pass an object in commit, with type as mutation name, like following:

```
context.commit({
     type:: "UPDATE_DATA", 
     data: Map.table(payload.type, data), 
     meta: meta
});
```

Comment: Right. I saw that on the web page but the way I interpreted it, using the payload object was a recommendation and not a technical mandatory thing. That's why I was surprised when I got squat in the meta place. It seems that putting everything in the payload is a requirement, not a suggestion. Anyway, I resolved it by using two separate mutations called from a single action. (It made more sense in the current situation.)

Comment: Dude, I just reviewed your rep graph. You've been on the lazy size for 4 years and then something happen - you reputation just exploded. What changed?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Well I started Vue :)