# Get undefined of response.data from axios that stored in vuex

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Get undefined of response.data `console.log(this.$store.getters.getData)`in vue component.

But, im able to get response.data using this statement `console.log(resp.data)`

I have tried `console.log(data)` in the success mutation, but it still returned undefined.

login.vue

```
    login: function() {
        let data = this.$store
          .dispatch("login", data)
          .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp.data);  -> it returned data
            console.log(this.$store.getters.getData);  -> it returned undefined

            }
          })
          .catch(err => {});
      }
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from 'qs'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    data: {},
  },
  mutations: {
    success(state, token, data) {
      state.status = 'success'
      state.token = token
      Vue.set(state, 'data', data)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    login({ commit }, data) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(url, qs.stringify(data))
          .then(resp => {
            commit('success', resp.data.token, resp.data)
            resolve(resp)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            commit('error')
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    },
  getters: {
    getData: state => state.data,
  }
})
```

`console.log(resp.data);  -> it returned data`
`console.log(this.$store.getters.getData);  -> it returned undefined`

Comment: I am not sure but i think you need first `.then((r)=> {return r.data}).then(()=>{console.log(this.$store.getters.getData)})`

Comment: Same, i got undefined again, i think is the mutation problem, after committing the data, it will become undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out why it returned undefined because the mutation only accepts 2 parameters called state and payload, so other parameters will not be passed.

Reference - [Can't send in a second parameter to the mutation in Vue store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201805/cant-send-in-a-second-parameter-to-the-mutation-in-vue-store)

Answer (score 0):

Try in mutation success instead Vue.set(state,'data',data) write state.data = data;

Comment: Sorry, you can check the code again because I missed the operation of just copying a few lines of code, so I have already edited the code. And the result of Vue.set(state,'data',data) and state.data = data; is the same - undefined.

Comment: Okey, i am checking your code. Of course, in the mutation success you have 2 arguments(token,data), but in action you call commit('success',data) with 1 one argument, because in mutation you have token = data, data = undefined.

Comment: but after i added token data as commit('success', token,data), it still return undefined for data but status and token have value.

Comment: What is the data which you pass in the login function when you dispatch event ?

Comment: My parameter query string.

Comment: Can you update your code, when you add token in commit ?